# Cannot type on textbox on Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have this html tag. What it does is to only allow number as input. It is working correctly in Chrome and Mozilla. But it doesn't work with Internet Explorer. I tried to turn off Protected Mode in Internet Explorer but still no luck.

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" size=6 maxlength=3 onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>
```

Comment: If you're only going to support IE9 and above try using "<input type="numeric">"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because IE 9 doesn't use `charCode` but `keyCode`. Try adding this instead:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" size=6 maxlength=3 onkeypress='return 
(event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) ||
(event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)'/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there about keyCode. This solved my problem.